# Direct images of basis elements for onto and open maps

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

[image]This problem(#39) should not be that difficult , I have a proof that I am not sure of ,since one can apply the definition of basis in 2 ways ...I am not sure if I have used onto correctly .....[image]

Comment: Can we know your attempt?

Comment: @Pippo I have added my solution...

Comment: Unless f is continuous, 39 is false.  X = R, T = usual topology, T^* = discrete topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need that $f$ is continuous too, otherwise $f: (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_{e}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_d)$, $f(x) = x$ (the first topology is the standard Euclidean one, the second the discrete topology on the reals), is a counterexample to your statement. Show where you use the continuity.., e.g.:

If $O$ is open in $Y$ then $f^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$, by continuity.
As $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $X$ we write

$$f^{-1}[O] = \bigcup \mathcal{B}' \text{ for some subfamily } \mathcal{B}' \subseteq \mathcal{B} \text{.}$$

Function images preserve unions and by surjectivity we have

$$O = f[f^{-1}[O] = f[\bigcup \mathcal{B}'] = \bigcup \{f[U]: U \in \mathcal{B}'\}$$
showing that $O$ is a union of a subfamily of the "image base".

The openness of $f$ is only needed to ensure that all $f[U]$ are open, so that the image family of $\mathcal{B}$ consists of open sets, as a base for $Y$ must.

Comment: Thanks Dr Brandsma , I am surprized that this famous topology book contained such an error.......

Comment: @herashefat what book? And in some texts an open map is also continuous by definition. You’d have to look it up.

Comment: Schaum's outline of General Topology ...In this book open is not continuous ...